# Validate domain name string with Javascript only .com and .net allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that validates domain names perfectly, but I need it to validate only ".com" and ".net'"s.

So a string "abcdefghi.co" or "abcdefghi.org" would be invalid.

Please give me a hand modifying the reg.

```
function frmValidate( domain ) {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$/.test(domain)) {
        //alert("Valid Domain Name");
        return true;
    } else {
        //alert("Enter Valid Domain Name");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is currently testing if there's "." followed by 2 or more characters at the end.

Change it to `^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:.(com|net))+$` and it will match only .com and .net domains

https://regexr.com/49fcn

Answer (score 2):

Because you only want to permit *one* `.` (followed by `.com` or `.net`), don't repeat the `(?:\. ...` group - instead, just *match* `\.`, followed by a group that alternates between `com` and `net`. You may also simplify the pattern by using the case-insensitive flag `/i`:

```
/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]\.(?:com|net)$/i
```

```js
const input = prompt('Domain to test?');
console.log(
  /^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]\.(?:com|net)$/i
  .test(input)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1) there could be more than one dot in a valid domain name, 
//    since subdomains don't make domain names invalid;
// 2) for the dot(s) placement, don't use some reg ex wizardry 
//    that will confuse and confound the next support guy 
//    (even if that's only you six months later)
function frmValidate( domain ) {
    // since domain could have subdomain like qwe.asd.zxc,
    // parse into substrings at "."
    var dParts = domain.split('.');
    // capture tld from end of list
    var tld = dParts[dParts.length - 1];
    // determine whether tld is "com" or "net"
    var isValid = ('com' === tld) || ('net' === tld);
    // for testing
    // alert('top level domain is: ' + tld + ' and is ' + (isValid?'':'NOT ') + 'valid');
    // advise caller
    return isValid;
};
```